# Fortran: "output statement overflows record" error when naming output files

Tags: dynamic, fortran, output

I'm trying to write dynamically to different file names (e.g. "output_0001.txt" "output_0002.txt"), but repeatedly get the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (66): output statement overflows record, unit -5, file
Internal Formatted Write
```

I've tried extending my "filename" character array to excessively large lengths, but it still isn't working. No idea why my string would be too big frown emoticon If I change the "filename" to a static character array, then it works fine. Any ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
character(30)::filename
...
write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") out_file_basename, "_", i, ".dat"
open(unit = 3, file = filename)
```

Comment: What is `out_file_basename`?

Comment: If it's a `character(30)` then that will be a problem - except when you have, as you say, as much longer `filename`.  Can you give a fully compilable stand-alone example?  [I also don't understand 'If I change the "filename" to a static character array, then it works fine.'", you perhaps mean `out_file_basename` here?]

Comment: @francescalus it's an argument from the command line, also taken as a 30 character array.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, you have something like

```
character(30)::filename, out_file_basename
...
write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") out_file_basename, "_", i, ".dat"
```

This will be a problem.  From other context, one it may be easy to solve.

There is a difference between

```
character(len=30) out_file_basename
out_file_basename = "output"  ! Or from get_command_argument
write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") out_file_basename, "_", i, ".dat"
```

and

```
write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") "output", "_", i, ".dat"
```

That difference is that `out_file_basename` is padded with 24 spaces (so is length 30), and the literal `"output"` isn't (and is length 6).  In the first you will need a character variable at least length 39.

The easy solution is to trim all that whitespace from `out_file_basename`:

```
write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") TRIM(out_file_basename), "_", i, ".dat"
```

but to be safe you want `filename` to be sufficiently large.